# syntax error, unexpected '?>' in Laravel View: D:..\WEB3\WEB\Pics\resources\views\home.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel, syntax

It looks like I have a little problem with which I can't find the solution. The only thing that I am finding on the net is that the problem can be from the PHP version if it's under 7.0, but mine is 7.4.5 
This is the code in the home.blade.php file

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">

        @if(count(#errors) -> 0)
                    @foreach(#errors->all() as $error)
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{$error}}
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                @endif

                @if(session('response'))
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                {{session('response')}}
                </div>

            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                   <div class="col-md-4">
                   <img src="" alt="" />
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

it gives me the mistake on the line with:

```
 @if(count(#errors) -> 0)
```

Do you have some suggestions on how can I fix it?

Comment: why are you using `#` ? it should be `if(count($errors) > 0)` instead of `#` use `$`

Comment: Check if all if. / foreach are closed.... IF(SESSION) looks not closed

Comment: `#` indicates a line comment in PHP meaning your `@if(count(#errors) > 0` is actually read as `if(count(` by PHP

Comment: Thanks all! ah... I guess I should look more carefully next time. It's working now ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not closed 'if condition' in a particular portion

Your Code :

```
 @if(session('response'))
      <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{session('response')}}
      </div>
```

This must be,

```
@if(session('response'))
     <div class="alert alert-success">
     {{session('response')}}
     </div>
@endif
```

Note : syntax error, unexpected '?>' in Laravel View. This kind of errors occur If you have not closed 'if condition' properly.